# How to GROUP and ORDER data in a Google Spreadsheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, sorting

I want to group and sort a particular data set. I've prepared the data using a `QUERY` function and using other functions.

Can I order by sum?

This is an example file I created: [order by sum](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AluAYY6ZHeWYdGFNeUxZMVVxdkhHRHlydGtuT1JsQUE#gid=4)

Comment: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125997/145551) – please improve your question.

Answer (score 6):

The best result would be to use the `QUERY`function:

```
=SORT(QUERY(Data!A1:B6;"select A, sum(B), count(B) group by A");2;FALSE)
```

Since the sum already has been sorted ascendingly, the `FALSE` statement in the formula will sort descending using column `2`.

Comment: If the query includes a header row, the header gets sorted as well. How would this be used with a header row?

Comment: @hughes The third optional parameter of the QUERY function allows you to indicate a header. If omitted, Google will do that for you and leave the headers un-touched.

Comment: This was super helpful. I was managed to produce nice graphs with very little effort from Google Forms data with this and the answer here https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/146778/29110

Answer (score 6):

Another way is from within the query:

```
=QUERY(Data!A1:B6;"select A, sum(B), count(B) group by A order by sum(B) desc")
```