# How do I make a bar chart that parses comma separated arrays in Google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google form with a multiple choice question. In the Google sheet, it places all of the checked responses in one cell separated by commas.

I'd like to generate a chart that counts the instances of each response across a whole set of responses, whole column, but it takes each combination of comma separated choices as unique for my bar chart.

What to do?

Editable Sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13EXYuSmWteaASzg0qP_hG_8uW2UNDmlX40IPXNGkVLU/edit#gid=0

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Hey, could you share some sample data in a dummy sheet ? could be helpful for us to better understand the problem

Comment: Please read how to and [share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311) so as you can be easier helped.

Comment: @pjmg Any thoughts?

Comment: @marikamitsos any thoughts?

Comment: Not really. Had a look at your sheet  just now trying to understand what you are looking for but it was just a replica of your screenshot. I still don't see it. I must be missing something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a way to split each values and count how many occurences of a unique reference exists :

```
=query(
transpose(split(JOIN(",",A5:A13),",",true,true)),
"SELECT Col1,count(Col1) group by Col1"
)
```

[image]

Comment: Looks great, except dealing with the space after the comma. Luckily my sheet is consistent.

Comment: @Costa you can try to add `=trim()` or replace them with a comma like this  `regexreplace("range"," ",",")`

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution based on the answer from pjmg that also deals with trailing space in the comma separated list correctly, and also sorts from high to low:

```
=sort(
   query(
transpose(ArrayFormula(trim(split(JOIN(",",'Ranked candidates'!V2:V999),",",true,true)))),
"SELECT Col1,count(Col1) group by Col1"
   ),
   2, false)
```

[More about ArrayFormula and Trim](https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/use-trim-function-split-google-sheets/0)

Comment: Here is more about SORT() with QUERY() https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/48775/how-to-group-and-order-data-in-a-google-spreadsheets